# Switch statement and type coercion

Tags: javascript

I read in the 'Professional JavaScript for Web Developers' by Nicholas Zakas in p.78 of 3rd edition (last one I think):

> The switch statement compares values using the identically equal
>   operator, so no type coercion occurs (for example the string "10" is
>   not equal to the number 10).

I made up some simple switch statement just to confirm and the result was different:

```
var num = "9";

switch (true) {
    case num < 0:
        alert("less than 0");
        break;

    case num >= 0 && num <10:
        alert("between 0 and 10");
        break;

    default:
        alert("False");

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pbxyvjyf/

So, type coercion is done: the `alert("between 0 and 10")` is chosen.
Have the rules changed or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will return `false`:

```
var num = "9";

switch (num) {
  case num < 0:
    alert("less than 0");
    break;

  case num >= 0 && num <10:
    alert("between 0 and 10");
    break;

  default:
    alert("False");

}
```

Therefore, the author is correct.

Comment: Thank you:) Now I understand what I was doing wrong. In fact, even in the example I gave the author was correct: 
 ´case num >= 0 && num <10:' (my example) num is a string, so converts to 0 because is false and then the  'alert("between 0 and 10");' appears. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that you're essentially comparing `"9"` with `true` and `false`. The expressions (`num < 0`, `num >= 0 && num < 10`) are evaluated before the case comparison is done.

Comment: @MikeC is exactly how you say! Now I understand. Thank you for make me understand what I done wrong.

Answer (score 10):

your case statements return a boolean so the type is correct

`num >= 0 && num <10` - returns true or false

but if i would do this

```js
switch (1) {
    case "1":
        console.log("never get here");
        break;

    case 1:
        console.log("but this works");
        break;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was sure I was doing something wrong and I am glad you have corrected me.

Answer (score 3):

You really aren't using the switch statement as intended. There should be an expression that's evaluated in the switch and the cases check for possible values. This is from one of the canonical examples:

```
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
    case 0:
        day = "Sunday";
        break;
    case 1:
        day = "Monday";
        break;
    case 2:
        day = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Wednesday";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Thursday";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Friday";
        break;
    case 6:
        day = "Saturday";
}
```

You are using the switch statement more like a bunch of ifs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

What that line from the documentation means is that no type coercion is used in comparing the `switch` value to each of the `case` values.

If the `case` expression itself is an expression that would involve type coercion, then there will obviously be type coercion taking place. `num >= 0 && num <10` evaluates to `true`, but the engine will use the "identically equal operator" in comparing that `true` against the `true` at the top of the `switch` statement. Since `true` is identically equal to `true`, the control flow goes into that `case`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Now I understand and I will not make the same mistake again:)

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert of javascript but I think that the rule that the author mentioned is valid in this case, for example:

```
   var num = "9";

    switch(num){

        case 9:
            alert("Yes the number is equal to: 9");
            break;
        default:
            alert("False");

    }
```

If you try to run this code you will see that the second alert will appear.

Hope that I helped you.. :)